# .htaccess rewrite to parent when parameter is given

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have a problem with a rewriterule in my .htaccess, I would like to redirect like this:

**www.mywebsite.com/category?p=2**

to

**www.mywebsite.com/category**

where category is variable.

I have my rewrite engine on and other redirects are working fine. This is what what I got so far:

```
RewriteRule ^/([a-z_\/]*)\?? /$1 [R=301,L]
```

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: You just want to discard the parameter when it is exactly p=2?

Comment: Are you using these rules in server.config ?

Comment: @DusanBajic no, it should redirect regardless but only if the p parameter is given.

Comment: @starkeen nope, I use it in my .htaccess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your request looks strange, but anyway, this should do it:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^p=
RewriteRule /?([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/? /$1? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: yeah, I'm not very experienced with rewrites but this works like a charm. thanks!

Comment: Keep in mind that it will not redirect if the query string is for example `?r=4&q=5&p=6`

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^category$ /category?p=2 [L]
```

It will give you the following URL:

`www.mywebsite.com/category`

Comment: Hmm.. this isn't working for me. i'm not very familiar with the syntax but shouldn't **category$** be something like **([A-Za-z])**  to make it variable? I now have this `RewriteRule ^/([A-Za-z])/?p=([0-9]+) /$1 [L,R=301]`. is there some way to get the **([A-Za-z])** part and use it in /$1  ?